# could this be a half step chord progression?

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory, chord-progressions, chord-inversions

At bar 3 to 4
the "Em7-5" goes to "Dm/F"
could this be consider as a half step chord movement ? because the inversion bass F ?
even tough "Em7-5" and the actual chord "Dm" without the inversion is not a half step related ?

if it is, how ??
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suppose if you reinterpreted bar 4 not as Dm/F but F6 with the fifth omitted you would then have two chords roots a half step apart - E to F.

It would help to know what happens in bar 5 to know if one or the other interpretation of the chord in bar 4 makes sense.

Comment: It goes to Gm7 Chord and the melody goes to F

Comment: By "half-step chord movement" are you asking if it is functioning as an approach chord?

Answer (score 1):

The use of Dmin/F (F in the bass) creates a smooth linear movement of that voice.  This does not make the progression chromatic.  It will still have the feeling of resolution to Dmin, rather than E-->F using bar chords or some similar device.  It is not uncommon in harmony to arrange the chords (i.e. voices that support the melody) in such a way that each voice has its own melodic structure.  I agree with Michael Curtis' last statement

"It would help to know what happens in bar 5 to know if one or the other interpretation of the chord in bar 4 makes sense."